# Coredata | Child Context memory Management

Tags: ios, core-data

I am creating some child context from the main context and I wanted to know do I need to release the child context?

I have a CoreData class which creates child context (this class is an arc enabled classes) but it can provide context to other classes which might not be arc classes.

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) createChildContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *childManagedContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    childManagedContext.parentContext = [self parentContext];
    return childManagedContext;
}
```

then some other class can get the child context

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [coredata createChildContext];
```

My question is do I need to release the context in this class or will it be auto managed by the arc class that created it since I am not retaining it.

Comment: We'll need to know a bit more to provide a reasonable answer; for example, are you using ARC? How do you create the child context? What do the [memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) say about your situation?

Comment: I have a CoreData class which creates child context (this class is an arc enabled classes) but it can provide context to other classes which might not be arc classes.

- (NSManagedObjectContext *) createChildContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *childManagedContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    childManagedContext.parentContext = [self parentContext];
    return childManagedContext;
}

then some other class can get the child context
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [coredata createChildContext];

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a pretty interesting question, since you're mixing ARC and non-ARC. As always, though, the [Memory Management Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) can help us decide what to do in this situation.

First off (as I think you already know), you don't have to release the context in the ARC class that creates it (inside `-createChildContext`). In fact, you can't explicitly release or autorelease it there, since the class is ARC - you can't do any manual memory management inside it.

Now let's look at the calling class. As you have it written, you *do not* have to release the context once you're done with it. Since you have not *taken ownership* of the context, you shouldn't tell the object that you're releasing it; it's not your place to give up ownership of an object you never owned in the first place.

Why haven't you taken ownership of the context? Well, as you have it written, you never:

- Explicitly retained the object (e.g. `[[coredata createChildContext] retain]`)
- Assigned the object to a `@property` marked `retain` or `strong`
- Got the object from a method starting with `alloc`, `new`, or `copy`

In this sense, you could think of the object being "managed by" the ARC class that created it, though that's a bit misleading; in reality, it doesn't matter who manages it, it just matters that you don't own it in the non-ARC calling class.

If you need to change that for some reason - say, you need the child context to stick around for a while, or you intend to use it throughout your class - you could consider one of the approaches listed above, where you *do* take ownership of the context. In that case, you would have to release it when you're done with it.

I highly recommend reading over the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1); it has a lot of very useful things to say about dealing with object ownership, among other topics.